# Boost.m4 linker error

Tags: c++, boost, ld, autoconf

I use `boost.m4` to find Boost. Here I go:

```
AC_PROG_CXX
AC_LANG([C++])
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11
BOOST_REQUIRE([1.48])
BOOST_SIGNALS
```

configure correctly find singals library, but when compiling, I get link error -- undefined reference to boost::signals::. Obvilously, ldflags, determined by `BOOST_SIGNALS`, do not get added to global flags. What I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should add `$(BOOST_SIGNALS_LIBS)` to `AM_LDFLAGS`.